# How to compute variable byte encoding of a postings list?

Tags: compression, information-retrieval

Lets say I have a postings list of 6 numbers 21992 23523 27822 28002 31010 33122. What would be the process to converting them to variable byte encoding?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable byte encoding"? Do you mean variable-length integer encoding? Do you just mean binary encoding?

Answer (score 0):

```
void encode(int value, char* code_list, int& len) {

  int bit_value = 0;
  int bit_num = 0;

  if (value < 128) {
    bit_num = 1;
  } else if (value < 16384) {
    bit_num = 2;
    bit_value = 1;
  } else if (value < 2097152) {
    bit_num = 3;
    bit_value = 3;
  } else {
    bit_num = 4;
    bit_value = 7;
  }
  value <<= bit_num;
  value += bit_value;
  memcpy(code_list + len, (char*) &value, bit_num);
  len += bit_num;

}
```